# Nested icons and Rails' link_to or button_to are not working with SLIM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, block, font-awesome

Why doesn't this work?

```
 # Note the `do` block
 = button_to 'Accept', firefighters_approve_path(entry), class: 'button is-success' do
    i.fa.fa-thumbs-up
```

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for String:0x007fec0bb7bcc8>

Why doesn't this work?

```
# Note no `do` block
= button_to 'Accept', firefighters_approve_path(entry), class: 'button is-success'
  i.fa.fa-thumbs-up
```

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for String:0x007fec0bc86b40

I want to use slim and fontawesome. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), it should be:

```
= button_to firefighters_approve_path(entry), class: 'button is-success' do
  i.fa.fa-thumbs-up
    |Accept
```

If you use a block, first argument should be a path and block contains name.

Comment: thanks. that helped. I used a pipe but I guess it's up to you

Comment: Too bad `bulma.io` only groups <a> tags, and not buttons :((

Comment: Interesting find, but I'm just not using bootstrap again for anything, ever again. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [`font-awesome-rails`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem, you'd be able to use the [`fa_icon`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers) helper:

```
= button_to fa_icon("thumbs-up", text: "Accept"), firefighters_approve_path(entry), class: 'button is-success'
```