# why is button_to not working with method: :put with slim in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, form-helpers, button-to

I want to trigger a put method for voting with emojis but button_to is not working with slim in rails

I have the following:

```rb
 = button_to vote_backend_session_path(@session.id, emoji: emoji), method: :put, remote: true, class: "btn btn-vote btn-xs bg-dark border-white hover-primary" do
      i.material-icons.align-middle. #{emoji.to_s}
      span.align-middle.text-white.ms-2 = @session.total(emoji)
```

it output the following in developer console:

[image]

So everytime a post action is triggered and my controller says it can't find the specified route.

I tried to change only in developer console to put, but then it triggers an `GET` instead of `PUT`

I looked at several questions regarding `button_to`:

- https://coderedirect.com/questions/280885/rails-button-to-applying-css-class-to-button

  - adding {} did not change anything
- [Rails 'button_to' is not working with 'send_file' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254614/rails-button-to-is-not-working-with-send-file-method)

  - using it with `method: 'get'` had no effect.
- [Nested icons and Rails' link_to or button_to are not working with SLIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455132/nested-icons-and-rails-link-to-or-button-to-are-not-working-with-slim)

  - putting icon before path gives error and indenting the second block gives strange output

I looked at the API doc as well [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) and was not able to find a solution.

So how to fix this and use button_to with rails in my case?

Answer (score 1):

your button type is `submit`, which will trigger the form to submit its fields

it shouldn't be inside a form tag
you can use the CSS technique to make it look like inside the form

Comment: Can you further specify what you mean be the css technique, do you think using link_to might be a better approach? Since button_to created the form. I tried to use it because in some cases my vote action creates a new instance of the vote class

Comment: I think it is not the problem because when I change to `post :vote` in routes everything is working fine

Comment: yea using link_to is better, you can ignore the CSS technique (styling) that I said above